# Missing files on a ZFS dataset

Tags: zfs

I have a few mysteriously missing files on one of my ZFS datasets. An example:

```
$ ls -l
ls: cannot access 'cover.jpg': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'metadata.opf': No such file or directory
total 17617
-????????? ? ?      ?             ?            ?  cover.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 hinsen hinsen 17999658 Nov 28  2019 'Lisp Lore_ A Guide to Programming the Lisp - Hank Bromley.pdf'
-????????? ? ?      ?             ?            ?  metadata.opf
```

This looks like there are directory entries that do not correspond to any file. Most operations on these files or the enclosing directory fail, I cannot even remove the whole directory.

With any other file system, I'd run "fsck" to fix this. With ZFS, all I am aware of for diagnostics is "zpool scrub", which shows no errors for my pool. So... how can I get my file system back into a working state?

System information:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- ZFS version:

```
$ zfs --version
zfs-0.8.3-1ubuntu12.12
zfs-kmod-2.0.3-8ubuntu6
```

Comment: Anything in `dmesg`?

Comment: `dmesg | grep zfs` only shows messages from systemd during startup.

Comment: What I did to move on is copy all the good files to a new dataset and replace the old one by it. Now everything looks OK. But I still wonder if there is a better way to handle such errors.